# How to set a table of contents line numbering to not start at page 1, in Pages '09?

Tags: mac, pages, word-processor

I am writing a document which requires the table of contents side-numbering scheme to start on the page after the table of content itselt. Basically the first 8 pages of the document should not count against the auto page numbering you can turn on.

There will be eight pages before this document that should have a custom side-numbering with roman numerals instead of the ordinary numbering, this should not count against the numbering format of the rest of the document that starts at the page after the table of contents. Is this possible with Pages 09?

If it is any help, here is the required template that the document should fulfill. (It's in norwegian): http://www.ub.uio.no/publisere/studenter/maler/mac-duo.docx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page numbering and format can be defined per section so you can get to the required format by creating two sections in your document and setting the page numbering accordingly

- Start with an empty document
- "Insert - Auto Page Number", select the "Section" option for "Show In" and set the format to roman numbers. This is now your TOC section.
- Use "Insert - Section break" to create a new section
- "Insert - Auto Page Number" again, select the "Section" option for "Show In" and set the format to arabic numbers
- With the cursor in the second section, open the inspector

  [image]

  and reset the page number to 1